# I get error with my PHP phonebook CRUD project

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, html-table, syntax-error

I'm getting an error on the `<?php endwhile; ?>` line.

**Error:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE);

**Code:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT* FROM contacts");
    ?>

    <table width="800" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5" border="2">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Contact No</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)); ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['contact_no']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
```

No record is showing in the table. The page is just showing the error.

Comment: See the semicolon in this statement `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));`, it should be `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):`

Comment: You're also not showing the initial opening `<?php` tag before setting `$result` to the return of `mysqli_query`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `endwhile;`, you should follow the `while`'s condition with a colon (`:`), not a semicolon (`;`):

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
<!-- Here --------------------------------------^ >
```